# Error in shinytest. Cannot detect my script is a R file

Tags: r, file, error-handling, shiny

I am trying to test an shiny application with the function shinytest.
I have made an record and get a new file:
[The picture show my test file and how I have specified the path to my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phCSv.png)

When I try to run the app I get the following error:
Error in is_rmd(path) : 
  Unknown whether app is a regular Shiny app or .Rmd: C:/Users/LUCBA/Projects/markt_to_marketpricingtool/test/myshinyapp.R

I know the file is an R file, but I get the error anyway.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Best Lucas

Comment: Showing pictures of code isn't as helpful as just pasting the code in the question. You seem to be showing contents of `test_1.R`. What exactly is in `myshinyapp.R`?

Answer (score 1):

This was the code that caused an error in Lucas's original question

```
app <- ShinyDriver$new("C:/Users/LUCBA/Projects/markt_to_marketpricingtool/test/myshinyapp.R")
```

The problem is that the first (`path`) argument to `shinytest::ShinyDriver$new` can only be a directory (containing either an `app.R` file *or* a `server.R`/`ui.R` pair) or R markdown `.Rmd` file. Sadly, a Shiny app file cannot be specified directly by name, so it can't be named `myshinyapp.R`.